# Python, цикл if в зависимости от значения False или True

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautiful-soup

Делаю парсер. В зависимости от того, есть часть `html` кода на странице с блоком `div` у которого `id="uk"` или нет, мне нужно прописать действия. Пробовал различные конструкции c циклом `while` и `if` и не могу понять в чём ошибка?

Есть код:

```
th = soup.find('div', id='uk')
print(bool(transcription_html))
```

Значение переменной `th = True`
Пробую написать цикл:

```
th = soup.find('div', id='uk')
if th is True:
    print("True")
else:
    print("False")
```

Получаю вывод `False`. Пробовал конструкцию `if th == True`, но результат тоже, получаю вывод `false`. Читал, что желательно использовать `is` а не `==`, когда проверка идёт через `True` или `False`.

Comment: [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3):

Условие `if th is True` (так же, как и `if th == True`) в этом коде никогда не выполниться, так как:

- в python ключевое слово `is` используется для проверки того, ссылаются ли обе переменные на один и тот же объект;
- метод `.find()` библиотеки `bs4` возвращает или объект класса `<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>`, или, если ничего не найдено, `<class 'NoneType'>` (в отличии от `.find_all()`, который возвращает или список элементов или пустой список, а не `None`).

Условие `if th` будет выполняться, если `th` имеет хоть какое-то "непустое" значение: не булевое `False`, не `None`, не пустой список (строка, сет) `[], '', {}` или не `0`, т.е. условие:

```
if th:
    print("True")
```

выполняется (возвращает `True`), в данном случае, если `th` - не `None`, а не `True`...

Comment: спасибо, что разъяснили!

Answer (score 2):

Для оператора if в случае если значение проверяется на True или False не требуется прописывать дополнительные конструкции, первый блок выполняется в случае True, второй в случае False. То есть код должен выглядеть следующим образом:

```
th = soup.find('div', id='uk')
if th:
    print("True")
else:
    print("False")
```